# Importing a .csv to OrientDB isn't working. OrientDB

Tags: nosql, orientdb

I wanted to import .csv file to OrientDB and I created a json file for it and ran it with oeatl.bat, but it says

```
OrientDB etl v.3.2.18 (build 75890139e2e64b786a59c95b913af9fbb86c5cfc, branch UNKNOWN) https://www.orientdb.com
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Error on unmarshalling JSON content for record: [MY JSON]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerJSON.fromStringV0(ORecordSerializerJSON.java:275)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerJSON.fromString(ORecordSerializerJSON.java:165)
```

There are more errors of a similar type and there's no new data in the database.

This is the json file:

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "C:/my_path/orientdb-community-3.2.18/orientdb-community-3.2.18/books1.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {} },
  "transformers": [
    { "vertex": { "class": "Books" } }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "plocal: C:/**my_path*/orientdb-community-3.2.18/databases/interests",
       "dbUser": "mydbusername",
       "dbPassword":"mydbpassword,
       "dbType": "graph",
       "classes": [
          {"name": "User", "extends": "V"}
         {"name": "Books", "extends": "Media"},
         {"name": "Movies", "extends": "Media"},
    {"name": "Games", "extends": "Media"},
    {"name": "Media", "extends": "V"},
         {"name": "Enemy", "extends": "Relationship"},
    {"name": "Romance", "extends": "Relationship"},
    {"name": "Family", "extends": "Relationship"},
    {"name": "Friend", "extends": "Relationship"},
    {"name": "Relationship", "extends": "E"},
    {"name": "Plays", "extends": "E"},
    {"name": "Watches", "extends": "E"},
    {"name": "Reads", "extends": "E"}
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

In command bard I cd to bin file and then I run

```
\oetl.bat books1.json.
```

Running oetl.sh doesn't work at all.